# if f is continuous then every preimage of lebesgue measurable is lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We know that if $f: A\to B$ is continuous and $E\subseteq B$ is a measurable Borel set, then $f^{-1}(E)\subseteq A$ is Borel measurable.

My question is that, If $E\subseteq B$ is Lebesgue measurable and $A=B=\mathbb{R}$ then how can prove that $f^{-1}(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: See the second answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706776/when-is-the-preimage-of-a-continuous-function-measurable?rq=1

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046947/class-of-lebesgue-lebesgue-measurable-functions